# Query Hive table created with built-in Serde from Spark app

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I have an hadoop cluster deployed using Hortonwork's HDP 2.2 (Spark 1.2.1 & Hive 0.14)

I have developped a simple Spark app that is supposed to retrieve the content of a Hive table, perform some actions and output to a file. The Hive table was imported using [Hive's built-in SerDe](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CSV+Serde).

When I run the app on the cluster I get the following exception :

```
ERROR log: error in initSerDe: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde not found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getDeserializer(MetaStoreUtils.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializerFromMetaStore(Table.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializer(Table.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getCols(Table.java:631)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.checkValidity(Table.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:1017)
    ...
```

Basically, Spark doesn't find Hive's SerDe (`org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde`)

I didn't find any jar to include at the app's execution and no mention of a similar problem anywhere. I have no idea how to tell Spark where to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .jar was in hive's lib folder, just had to add it on launch with --jar and know where to look !

```
--jars /usr/hdp/XXX/hive/lib/hive-serde-XXX.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a shaded JAR of your application which includes hive-serde JAR. Refer [this](http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/missing_dependencies_in_jar_files.html)

Answer (score 0):

add jar file in spark config spark.driver.extraClassPath.
Any external jar must be added here , then spark environment will automatically load them.

Or use spark-shell --jars command

example

```
spark.executor.extraClassPath /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/csv-serde-0.9.1.jar
```

Comment: I was doing it with the --jars but couldn't find the specific jar, sorry if I wasn't clear enough